# using variable name in lodash collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

Question is bit crazy. Is there any possibility to using variable name instead of another, clearly, consider the following code where I have to switch over to any variable name "people" or "student" accordingly

```
 var people=[
      {name:"akash",age:25},
      {name:"abi",age:22}
   ];

 var student =[
     {name:"Sanjai",age:25},
     {name:"Ravi",age:35},
      {name:"Bopara",age:36}
 ];
var variables=["people","student"];

 var result= _.find(variables[0], function(o) { return o.age < 35; });
   console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just put variables into array instead of strings:

```
var variables=[people, student];
```

Full example:

```js
var people=[
     {name:"akash",age:25},
     {name:"abi",age:22}
 ];

var student =[
     {name:"Sanjai",age:25},
     {name:"Ravi",age:35},
     {name:"Bopara",age:36}
 ];

var variables=[people, student];

var result= _.find(variables[0], function(o) { return o.age < 35; });

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```